# Записать Parcelable в Parcelable

Tags: java, android, классы, android-fragment, android-parcelable

Добрый день!

Имеются два класса, которые реализуют интерфейс Parcelable. Они практически одинаковые по структуре, различаются только переменными. Вот пример одного класса.

```
class Box implements Parcelable {
   double length;
   double width;

   public Box(double length, double width) {
         this.length = length;
         this.width = width;
   }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeDouble(length);
    dest.writeDouble(width);
}

public static final Creator<Box> CREATOR = new Creator<Box>() {
    @Override
    public Calc createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Box(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Calc[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Box[size];
    }
};
}
```

Созданные в процессе сбора информации экземляры этих классов передаются через конструктор в другой экзепляр класса, который проводит арифметические операции с данными этих классов. В итоге, конечный экземпляр, который содержит в себе два класса реализующих Parcelable, необходимо передать во Fragment посредством setArgument, а потом оттуда получать к ним доступ через getArgument. Можно ли так сделать? И как?

Answer (score 1):

Да, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239557/3212712).

Для записи Parcelable объекта есть метод `writeParcelable`

```
Box obj;
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeParcelable(obj , flags);

    }
}
```

Для чтения соответственно `readParcelable`

```
obj = (Box)in.readParcelable(Box.class.getClassLoader());
```

---

Со списками так:

запись списка `dest.writeTypedList(boxes);`
чтение списка `in.createTypedArrayList(Box.CREATOR);`

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите как передать Parcelable Arraylist. Я вижу имеется только dest.writeParcelableArray

Comment: @АрсенШогенов, раз нет метода для списка, то просто переедите список в массив методом `toArray()` и обратно, вроде, можно примерно так же - в конструктор `List`-a передать массив.

Comment: @АрсенШогенов 

запись списка `dest.writeTypedList(boxes);`

чтение списка `in.createTypedArrayList(Box.CREATOR);`